# How can I query an ODBC connection in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, hive, odbc

I would like to run a query from Sqlite on my laptop to connect to Hive via ODBC and create a table from the output.

Sqlite and the ODBC connection are setup and working.

What is the syntax I need to use to access my ODBC connection from Sqlite?

In SQL Server I can do the following:-

`SELECT * INTO my_sqlserver_table FROM (select * FROM openquery([my_odbc_connection],'SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM my_hive_table')) a;`

Comment: sqlite ? Or SQL Developer? Sqlite and hive are both different DBMS.

Comment: I am using Sqlite. I want to import data into Sqlite from Hive using an ODBC connection. I can do this from SQL Server, so it must be just a case of finding the correct syntax.

Comment: sqlite queries cannot be run against Hive... If you want to export Hive data to another system, you can use Sqoop, which uses JDBC. Or you can use Spark to copy dataframe to your local sqlite file, also using JDBC

Comment: So Sqlite can't query from an ODBC connection?